# Как загружать компоненты в зависимости от ответа сервера?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-resource

Что имеется:

1. *vue*-файл (**естественно что-то тут не так, прошу помощи.**)

   ```
   <template >
     <div class="app" >
        {{dataArticle}} //подгружаем сюда сгенерированые данные
     </div>
   </template>
   <script>
   import LoadFunctions from '@/services/LoadFunctions'
   export default {
     name: 'settings',
     data () {
       return {
         dataArticle:  '' 
       }
     },
     mounted () {
       this.getArticle('10') // хочу получить статью номер 10
     },
     methods: {
       async getArticle (data) { // выполняем функцию из mounted
         const response = await LoadFunctions.getArticle(data) // отправляем запрос 
         this.dataArticle = response.data // получаем данные
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Отправляем данные на сервер (файл `/services/LoadFunctions`)

   ```
   export default {
     getArticle (data) {
       return Api().post('getArticle', data)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Сервер обрабатывает запрос, обращается к монгодб ищет нужную статью.
   возврат такой

   ```
   data: {
     used_component:  'article_with_video',
     component_data: {
       header: 'Заголовок',
       text: 'Текст статьи',
       video_url: 'http ссылка' 
     } 
   }
   ```

И тут у меня проблемы

json-то я определил в ответе, но как мне подгрузить именно этот `used_component`, передав в него `component_data`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого необходимо создать компонент-обертку,в котором будет прописан шаблон использования встроенных компонентов

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <component :is="used_component" :data="component_data"></component>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import AwesomeComponent from "../AwesomeComponent";
import AnotherAwesomeComponent from '../AnotherAwesomeComponent'

export default {
  name: "Main",
  components: {
    AnotherAwesomeComponent ,
    AwesomeComponent ,
  },
data() {
    return {
      used_component: '',
      component_data: {},
    };
  },
created() {
 sendRequestToServer().then(response => {
    this.component_data = response.component_data;
    //в поле used_component должно приходить название компонента
    this.used_component = response.used_component;
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component