# Повесить несколько разных событий по условию. Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Представим, что нам с сервера приходит название компонента и мы его должны отобразить. Вот как в этом вопросе: [Как загружать компоненты в зависимости от ответа сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927179/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/927186#927186)

У нас есть шаблон, которые это делает.

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <component :is="used_component" :data="component_data"></component>
  </main>
</template>
```

На практике, каждый из таких компонентов может эмитить кучу разных кастомных событий, на которые нам надо подписаться. Выглядеть это будет так

```
<template>
   <main class="main">
      <component 
         :is="used_component" 
         :data="component_data"
         @customEvent_1="handler_1"
         @customEvent_2="handler_2"
         //и т.д
     >
     </component>
    </main>
 </template>
```

Таким образом, получиться, что каждый из компонентов будет подписан на все возможные обработчики, которые будут генерироваться, как используемым компонентом, так и не используемыми. Как этого избежать и указать обработчик и событие, по условию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этого вопроса необходимо воспользоваться методом, который будет возвращать названия события и его обработчик

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <component 
     :is="used_component" 
     :data="component_data"
     v-on="getEvent(used_component)"
    ></component>
  </main>
</template>

<script>

export default {
methods: {
  getEvent(nameComponent) {
     if (nameComponent === "component_1") return { 'customEvent_1': this.handler_1 };
     if (nameComponent === "component_2") return { 'customEvent_2': this.handler_2 };
     return {}
   }
  }
};
</script>
```