# Как во vue lинамечески добавить событие click в определенную ячейку таблицы

Tags: javascript, vue.js, table, click

столкнулся с проблемой

Если код компонента table.vue, которые выводит в таблицу массив объектов source

```
<template>
    <div>
      <table border="1">
         <tr v-for="(tr,i) in source" :key="i">
            <td v-for="(td, ii) in tr" :key="ii">{{ td }}</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       source: [
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        },
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        },
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        }
       ]
    };
  },
 methods:{
   test(){
    console.log(1)
   }
 }

</script>
```

Как динамически добавить событие @click только тем столбцам, которые соответствуют свойству "а" каждого объекта массиве source.
Т.е. чтобы в полученной таблице, в данном примере, можно было нажать на каждую ячейку второго столбца и выполнился метод test()

Answer (score -1):

```
<template>
    <div>
      <table border="1">
         <tr v-for="(tr,i) in source" :key="i">
            <td v-for="(td, ii) in tr" :key="ii" v-on="{click: td.a === 'asd' ? test : ()=>{}}">{{ td }}</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       source: [
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        },
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        },
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        }
       ]
    };
  },
 methods:{
   test(){
    console.log(1)
   }
 }

</script>
```

Более универсальный способ можете увидеть здесь [Повесить несколько разных событий по условию. Vuejs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930960/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-vuejs)

Comment: Да, но так @click повесится на каждую ячейку таблиц, а так чтобы повесился только на каждую вторую? и без привязки к содержимому ячейки?

Comment: В вопросе, про четность речь не шла: `которые соответствуют свойству "а" каждого объекта массиве source` У Вас, все объекты в массиве одинаковые.

Comment: Согласен неудачный пример
в идеале массив объектов может быть типа такого
source: [
        {
         q: 'qwe',
         a: 'asd',
         b: 'asd'
        },
        {
         q: 'qwe',         
         b: 'asd',
         a: 'uio
        },
        {
         a: 'nbf',
         b: 'asd',
         q: 'qwe'
        }
       ]