# Vue Router | Организация проекта, динамические маршруты внутри компонентов

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Имеется проект на Vue.

Структура приложения следующая

```
|   App.vue
|   main.js
|   router.js
|               
+---components
|   |   Notifications.vue 
|   |           
|   +---hud
|   |       PlayerHud.vue
|   |       Showpass.vue
|               
+---store
|   |   index.js
|   |   
|   \---modules
|       |       
|       +---hud
|       |       index.js
|       |       playerhud.js
|       |       showpass.js
|       |       
|       +---notifications
|               
\---views
    |   Hud.vue
```

Сам файл Hud.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="hud">
        <player-hud></player-hud>
        <show-pass></show-pass>
        <notifications id="notifications"></notifications>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import PlayerHud from "../components/hud/PlayerHud";
    import Showpass from "../components/hud/Showpass";
    import Notifications from "../components/Notifications";

    export default {
        components: {
            PlayerHud,
            Showpass,
            Notifications
        }
    };
</script>
```

Маршруты:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import Hud from './views/Hud';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/hud',
            component: Hud
        }
    ]
});
```

---

Суть такова, что есть компонент PlayerHud.vue, в котором должны быть маршруты, есть компонент ShowPass.vue, в котором тоже есть маршруты.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы маршруты не мешали друг-другу.

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/hud',
            component: Hud,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/playerhud',
                    component: Stats,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'settings',
                            component: Settings,
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'other',
                            component: Other,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    path: '/show-pass',
                    component: ShowPass,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: 'first',
                            component: First,
                        },
                        {
                            path: 'second',
                            component: Second,
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Если в таком варианте я сделаю, то при переходе по маршруту /playerhud у меня закроется /show-pass все внутренние вкладки, тогда как организовать роутинг, чтобы не при переходах ничего не перекрывалось и не закрывалось, а работало как и должно быть.

Какова должна быть структура? Быть может есть другие варианты, которые я ещё не видел.

Comment: И всё-таки  я не понимаю чего Вы хотите... Вы хотите разбить страницу на фреймы и открывать в них отдельные страницы? Или может держать живой страницу Home.vue, пока открыта Aside.vue? Или что?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы внутри компонентов подключаемых в файле `Home.vue` я мог динамически изменять маршруты, но при этом чтобы маршруты в остальных компонентах, таких как `Aside`, `Footer`, `Header`, не были сброшены, а работали независимо. @ЖекаДиулин

Comment: Ээээ... Изменять маршруты - это типа зачем? Есть такая штука, как динамический маршрут: "user/:id/", "place/:action/". И ничего менять не надо! Достаточно только прочитать значение из параметров id/action и сразу понятно что от тебя хотят...

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин , то есть необходимо использовать параметры в url, а в компоненте просто ловить параметр и на основе этого подключать компонент? верно?

Comment: _"Если я переключусь на маршрут Aside.vue"(с)_. Путаница какая-то, маршрут у роутера это что-то типа `/path/:any` а не views. Возможно вы хотите это https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html - где можно динамически подгружать нужные компоненты в зависимости от `:any` или иных параметров.

Comment: Динамические компоненты во Вью тоже есть. И можно рендерить любой компонент на выбор в зависимости от параметра маршрута или других условий. Маршруты менять не нужно

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg данный пример не очень понятен, как его применить на данном вопросе, я просто хотел чтобы в строку применялись параметры и каждый компонент мог подчерпнуть что-то, что ему нужно и на основе этого отрисовать компонент

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы хотите добавлять параметры как `path?param`. Эти параметры видны внутри любого компонента в `$route.query:{...}`. На основе этого можно писать любую логику изменения, подгрузки и замены компонентов внутри ваших блоков.

Comment: решение задачи, если оно есть, зависит от ответа на вопрос: какие компоненты должны отобразиться, при прямом переходе по тому или иному урлу (через адресную строку)?

Comment: @Дмытрык нужен подробный пример я так понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключ к ответу кроется в атрибуте `name` компонента `router-view`.  [Документация](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/named-views.html#%D0%B2n%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2n%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Правда, для каждого варианта урла придется харкодить компоненты, которые будут отображаться. Что я имею ввиду: если пользователь, в Окне-1 перешел в Под-Окно-1, а потом, при переходе в Окне-2 в Под-Окно-2 - в Окне-1 отобразится то Под-Окно, которое записано в настройках роутера, а не то, которое до этого выбрал пользователь. Это неудобство я не смог обойти.

```js
const Base = Vue.component('vbase', {
  template: `<div>
    <div>Base</div>
    <router-link to="/home/house">/home/house</router-link> ||
    <router-link to="/home/shed">/home/shed</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <router-view name="second"></router-view>
  </div>`
});

const Child1 = Vue.component('child-one', {
  template: `<div class="child">
    <b>Child_1 </b>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <router-link to="/home/house/kitchen">/home/house/kitchen</router-link> |||
    <router-link to="/home/house/bedroom">/home/house/bedroom</router-link>
  </div>`
});

const Child2 = Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div class="child">
    Child_2
    <router-view name="second"></router-view>
    <router-link to="/home/shed/cellar">/home/shed/cellar</router-link> |||
    <router-link to="/home/shed/loft">/home/shed/loft</router-link> 
  </div>`
});

const GrandChild1 = Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template: `<div>
    GrandChild1
  </div>`
});
const GrandChild2 = Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template: `<div>
    GrandChild2
  </div>`
});
const GrandChild3 = Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template: `<div>
    GrandChild3
  </div>`
});
const GrandChild4 = Vue.component('grand-child', {
  template: `<div>
    GrandChild4
  </div>`
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      component: Base,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'house/',
          components: { default: Child1, second: Child2 },
          children: [
            {
              path: 'kitchen',
              components: { default: GrandChild1, second: GrandChild2 }
            },
             {
              path: 'bedroom',
              components: { default: GrandChild3, second: GrandChild2 }
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          path: 'shed/',
          components: { default: Child1, second: Child2 },
          children: [
            {
              path: 'cellar',
              components: { default: GrandChild1, second: GrandChild2 }
            },
             {
              path: 'loft',
              components: { default: GrandChild1, second: GrandChild4 }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { path: '/', component: Base }
  ]
});

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>`
});
```

```css
.child{
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.1/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
```

Мое мнение таково, что с именованными вьюшками, глубже 2-го уровня, лучше не зарываться. На 3-ем уровне и ниже,[лучше воспользоваться динамическими компонентами.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927179/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/927186#927186)

Comment: Роутинг глубже 3-го уровня не панацея, вполне устраивает и компоненты внутри 2ого уровня. Суть в том, чтобы глубже 2-го уровня компоненты не перекрывались внутри себя. Окно-1, открывает Под-окно-2, затем открывает Окно-2 и потом Под-окно-1, при этом под-окно-2 не будет закрываться и будет работать независимо.

Comment: Если получится сделать всё через компоненты глубже 2-го уровня, то данный ответ решит проблему. Я думал что мешать маршруты в компонентах это плохо, но понимаю что моя идея и есть плохое решение.

Comment: в моем примере, Ваш вариант, описанный в 1-ом комментарии, вроде как, реализован

Comment: Проблема в том, что при переходе в одном окне, в другом под-окне сбрасываются до дефолтного состояния. Если вынос маршрутов в компонент, как вы подчеркнули, поможет решить проблему с этим, то этот вариант подходит и будет помечен как решённый, спасибо за ответ!