# Динамический рендеринг разметки Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне с back-end приходит такой массив:

```
content: [{
  tag: 'p',
  children: [
    {
      tag: 'span',
      content: 'Something text',
      attributes: {
        href: null
      }
    },
   {
     tag: 'router-link',
     content: 'Something text',
     attributes: {
       href: '/task/id/test'
     }
   }
 ]}]
```

Как мне динамически создавать контент, если вложенность может быть совершенно разная?

Спасибо!

***Решил таким способом:***
[image]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загружать компоненты в зависимости от ответа сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927179/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: Не совсем, там под разные компоненты. У меня будет один компонент, просто нужно создавать в нем контент, опираясь на вложенность, что приходит с сервера

Comment: Поверьте, это именно то, что надо. Или Вам еще надо про v-for сказать?

Comment: Согласен, вместо разных компонентов я вставлю всего один компонент, а как потом в том компоненте обрабатывать данные? И динамически создавать теги?

Comment: Возможно проще присылать саму разметку и выводить её через `v-html`